# Evaluating the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \lambda^{k \gamma}/(k!)^{\gamma}$ for $\gamma \geq 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I have been looking for a result pertaining to the evaluation of the series

> $$T(\lambda, \gamma) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{k \gamma}}{(k!)^{\gamma}}$$

for $\lambda>0$ and $\gamma \geq 1$ (I am mostly interested in $\gamma \in [1,2]$). By the ratio test the series converges. For the specific case of $\gamma = 1$, we clearly have $T(\lambda, 1) = e^{\lambda}$, but is there also such a closed-form expression for $\gamma>1$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: $T(\lambda,2)=I_0(2\lambda)$ is (related to) the modified Bessel function $I_0$. Other cases are unlikely to have "names" (let alone closed forms).

Comment: @metamorphy I see the similarity, that settles the case of $\gamma = 2$. Thank you.

Comment: For integer values of $\gamma$, these are hypergeometric functions.

Comment: As @ClaudeLeibovici said.  $T(\lambda,7) = {}_0F_6( ;1,1,1,1,1,1 ;\lambda^7)$.  I think only cases $\gamma = 1,2$ have ever been found useful for anything.